# Java Hibernate connect as different user

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm using Java Hibernate to connect to ORACLE DB. I wanted to connect to DB as normal user and also as sysdba.

Connecting to sysdba is to get the openmode.

Any one knows how to implement multiple user in java hibernate

Comment: what are you using XML configure  or annotation?

Comment: I'm using XML 


Here is a sample for normal user. I need to query as sysdba also...


<property name="dialect">
   org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect
  </property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.179.9.31:1521:db1
  </property>
  <property name="connection.username">abcd</property>
  <property name="connection.password">abc123</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">
   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  </property>
  <property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">
   Oracle 9i Connector
  </property>